# mbstring is missing for phpmyadmin in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I installed PHP 7.4 and then PHP 8.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.

But after installing `phpmyadmin`, I ran `sudo phpenmod mbstring`. It is returning this warning:

```
WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.4/mods-available
WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.4/mods-available
```

I need to use PHP 8.1 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

To remove this warning, you have to install `php7.4-mbstring` package. You don't have to do this if you don't plan to use PHP 7.4.

```
sudo php7.4-mbstring
```

If you want to use PHP 8.1 as the default for the Apache, you have to disable PHP 7.4 and enable the `php8.1` module:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php8.1
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you are planning to use PHP 8.1 from the command line, you also have to use `update-alternatives`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1
```